# Sending feedback mail using java mail using jsp

Tags: jsp, email, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send the feedback email using java mail in JSP. My code is

```
<%@ page import = "java.io.*,java.util.*,javax.mail.*"%>
<%@ page import = "javax.mail.internet.*,javax.activation.*"%>
<%@ page import = "javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*" %>

<%
   String result;
   String to = "receiver@mail.com";
   String from = "sender@mail.com";
   String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
   Properties properties = System.getProperties();
   properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
   Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
   try {
      MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
      message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
      message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));
      message.setSubject("subject");
      message.setText("message to  send");  
      Transport.send(message);
      result = "Sent message successfully....";
   } 
   catch (MessagingException mex) {
      mex.printStackTrace();
      result = "Error: unable to send message....";
   }
%>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Send Email using JSP</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <center>
         <h1>Send Email using JSP</h1>
      </center>
      <p align = "center">
         <% 
            out.println("Result: " + result + "\n");
         %>
      </p>
   </body>
</html>
```

But it always shows Error: unable to send message.... 
Is there any problem with the code....?
I tried to print the error message and it shows authentication error, Unable to send like that.
As it's a feedback email and I don't want the user to provide his/her password to send the email please provide a better solution(I have included the mail.jar and activation.jar in library folder).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your own credentials to login to the mail server.

Comment: oh sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm using my own credentials. I just changed them before sharing it here.

Comment: I think you're confusing recipients with credentials.  You need to login to your mail server.  Use the [Transport.send method that takes a username and password](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/Transport.html#send-javax.mail.Message-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).  If that doesn't work, post the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug).  You should also fix any of these [common mistakes](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes).

Comment: Thank you so much, sir. I have sent a successful email. But I don't want it to be in this way. As when a user sends a feedback email he only specifies his email-id, no password is asked anywhere. And I'm trying to do the same. Yes, when I'm giving password it's sending the email but no websites or application ask for the sender's password. How can I do this without giving sender's password.

Comment: You can't send a message that pretends to come from a user without specifying the user's mail server and password.  You can send a message using your credentials and include in the body of the message the information about the user.